# Internet Explorer 9 ignores my Stylesheet

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hyperlink

I am currently setting up a new page and wanted to test it with the Internet Explorer (9). I thought it was not going to be a problem, because it does work with FireFox, Opera, and Chrome (newest Versions). However, the IE does not attempt to load my style sheet.

I already searched Google and stackoverflow for an answer, but nothing helped.

My page looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Hello World</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link href="css/main_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
```

etc.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help in advance!

PS: I validated the page and the css styles. No errors found.

**Edit (July 2014):**

Hey, I'm sorry I forgot to update this question for so long. The answer is simple. I had to put `@charset "utf-8";` at the beginning of my stylesheet. That's all it took to make it work. Cheers!

Comment: What do you get when you look at the console?

Comment: It shows "loading" (in the CSS tab), and that's it

Comment: http://www.s-fp.de/stackoverflow/main_styles.css (validator link: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.s-fp.de%2Fstackoverflow%2Fmain_styles.css )

Comment: what does !important mean in    a.no-decoration{
 text-decoration:none !important;
 font-weight:normal;
 cursor:pointer;
}  ???

Comment: @juankysmith - lol it means that the property overrides any other declaration no matter where in the cascade...

Comment: it overrides parent styles. that shouldn't be the problem: it works for my other sites. i don't think that looking at the css will help, because he doesn't even load it :/

Comment: @easwee Thanks! I have learnt something new! :)

Comment: @user1007003 does the problem happen on www.s-fp.de or on some other test site?

Comment: on a test site. the website up at the moment is old, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the reference of the link: `href="/css/main_styles.css"` or `href="../css/main_styles.css"`

Comment: can you access to the stylesheet writing http://url_to_your_project/css/main_styles.css ??

Comment: Yes, I can. As I said, it works with the other browsers. That's why I cannot figure it out

Comment: I already restarted the server and tried a plain html file. also doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious possible cause I can think of for this would be that your server is providing the wrong mime type of the CSS file. It might be that IE is more picky about this sort of thing than the other browsers you've tested.

Check what the mime type is by checking the HTTP headers, either in one of the other browsers debugging tools or with an HTTP sniffing program like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Fiddler will also be good for sniffing exactly what is going on when you try to make the request using IE. Whether it's a mime type issue or something else, this will be the best way to find out exactly what's happening.

Finally, you could also try opening the stylesheet's URL directly in IE. That will prove that IE can access the URL.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I can open it directly. (see juankysmith's comment).  I will have a look at the mime type, thank you

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue with Internet Explorer 11, it's weird but if you rename the stylesheet to anything without the word "style" it will start working!

This is only the case when the accessing the file local on a machine, on a web server it will work fine